# ubuntu samba not connecting from mac

Tags: samba, ubuntu-12.04

I have an ubuntu 12.10 VM with samba v 3.6.6 installed:

```
Ubuntu 12.10 (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-44-generic x86_64)
```

On my mac i can connect to the smb share no problems:

```
smb://www.tests.net
```

Finder then asks for a username and pword, then asks which share to mount.

Running on a live server:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-virtual x86_64)
```

I samba 3.6.3 installed with the same conf settings, when i try to connect to the server:

```
smb://www.liveserver.net
```

The connection times out and asks if i have the correct ip.. I have tried both the domain and ip but each keeps timing out.

Am I missing something?

I can't see that it would be a permission issue as the connection is not even made with the server.. it is as if samba is not even installed on the server or running.

Comment: Is this server out on the public internet?

Comment: maybe firewall blocking ?

Answer (score 0):

1 word.  Firewall.  Most ISPs deliberately block the default SMB ports on the public Internet.  (445, 135-139) (Due to Microsoft's inept security when it comes to networking.)  Just for testing purposes... try putting something else on a few of those ports for testing... and I think you'll find them blocked.  Typically, you can call the ISP and ask them politely to unblock all traffic... and they will.